# Q: A question about uniqueness of morphisms

Tags: category-theory

If i have a unique morphism $f\colon A\longrightarrow B$ and unique $g\colon B\longrightarrow A$ in a category, then f and g are isomorphisms?

Comment: You know that $f\circ g$ is a morphism from $B$ to $B$, but you have no reason to believe that it is the identity morphism. Same for $g\circ f$.

Answer (score 5):

No !

For instance if you have a zero object, it could go wrong.

In the category of groups, $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ are clearly not isomorphic, but there are unique morphisms in both directions (the zero morphism)

Answer (score 0):

**Definition 0** Suppose $f:A\rightarrow B$ is a morphism in a category $\mathscr C$. $f$ is a isomorphism if and only if $\exists g:B\rightarrow A \ such \ that \ g\circ f=1_A \ and \ f\circ g=1_B$. We say that, $g$ is inverse of $f$ and $f$ is inverse of $g$.

**Definition 1** In category $\mathscr C$, a morphism $f:A\rightarrow B$ is unique iff $\nexists g:A\rightarrow B$ such that $g \ne f$.

Now, in an attempt to answer your question, $f, g$ is unique, but they will not be isomorphisms, until it is shown that they are inverse of each other. Further, assuming @Max is correct with his counter-example, then in general, it is not the case that, if $f, g$ are unique, then $f\circ g = 1_B$ and $g\circ f=1_A$.